# A `cd` command in an executed Powershell script still affects the current session

Tags: windows, powershell, working-directory, subshell

Coming from the Unix world, scripts when executed (as opposed to sourced) are run in a subshell, and thus variable declarations and `cd` commands do not affect the actual current session (the one where we type our commands).

For reference:

```
# Executing a script
./myscript.ps1

# Sourcing a script
. ./myscript.ps1
```

Very surprised (and quite frankly annoyed) to see than in Powershell, executing a script will still affect my current session regarding `cd` commands (but not declared variables).

How can I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: the working dir is the one that the system sees as "current". of _course_ it changes the location that _anything_ sees as current. [*grin*]

Comment: Scripts are executed in the current session, that's the way it is. Either use `pushd` and `popd` pairs instead of `cd`, or a `try { $initialDirectory = pwd; ... }`/`finally { cd $initialDirectory }` wrapper, or explicitly start a new powershell process to run your script.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing as an alternative, but thanks anyway :). However I still feel this is a dubious behavior design, as variable declarations are still not propagated in the current session when *executing* the script, as opposed to *sourcing* it. So the execution isn't actually in the current session, it's a hybrid behavior between executing and sourcing.